# Logging issue with Log4j in Flink cluster?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-flink

I have a program in which Log4j is used to log some information. When I test in the IDE/Intellij, log file could generate successfully. While when I submit this task to flink stand alone cluster. I couldn't find any corresponding log file in any worker node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standalone mode, Flink writes its log files to `FLINK_DIR/log` per default. `FLINK_DIR` is the home directory of Flink. You can control the logging behaviour by changing the file `FLINK_DIR/conf/log4j.properties`. There you can also change the path via `log4j.appender.file.file=FILE_PATH` to which the logging files are written.

Comment: Hi, in my program there is also a log4j.properties file. Why configuration in this file doesn't work?

Comment: In standalone mode of deployment, flink adds the path to log4j.properties file present in the conf/ directory for logging and so the property file in your project is being overwritten.

Comment: Does this work when running a job in a cluster?  For instance, my FLINK_DIR/conf/log4j.properties points to a log file that is on a NFS path.  So when Flink tasks run across several machines, would they all access the log file in this NFS path?   Or should the log file be specified to be on local disk on each host?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using yarn cluster,then the log is stored at `/hadoop/yarn/logs/$application_id$`